# How to find the match and return the match in another column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have two columns- column A which extends upto 11027(values) and column I which extends to 42000(values).Both the columns contains some code details.

Something like this

```
A               B               
q123           as124
as124          gh456
ff45           q123
dd1             dd2
xx2
xx3
xx4
and so on...
```

I want to find if the names in column A exists in column B then return that b value in another column.
say for example if it finds a match "q123" in the b list then it has to be in the c list
.

Comment: have you tried already something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$8811,1,FALSE),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily just using the vlookup function.

type into the first cell in column C:
=vlookup(A2,B:B,1,false)

This function will look for the value in cell A2, use the first column in the range to find the value in A2 (in this case, I only put one column down, Column B), return the corresponding value in the "1" (first) column, and I only included Column B, and the "false" requires that the value in Column B is an exact match.

Then, fill down column C until it has the same amount of rows as column A. If a value in Column A is not found, then it'll return #N/A, and then you can quickly delete those values from Column C.

Comment: but ,i am expecting something like C: =vlookup(value ,array,value)

Comment: i mean if the value is present in the arry then it has return the value not a "1" or "0"

Comment: Yes, the formula I provided should work to find if there is a matching value in Column B in Column A and return the value in column B.